# PowerShell - jagged array filtering with pipeline in pipeline

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a jagged array $h that I would like to filter. One way to do this is to use pipelines in pipelines, like in the following example:

```
$h = ((‘a’,’b’,’a’), (‘c’,’d’), (‘a’, ‘f’)) 
$h | foreach {$_ | Where-Object {$_ -Like 'a'} } | foreach { if ($_.Count -gt 0) {<% DO SOMETHING %> }}
```

As you can see, I am trying to start a new pipeline in the foreach {} statement, hoping it will not interfere with the outer pipeline, but it does. The output is no longer a jagged array, but simply an one dimensional array consisting of strings: `(‘a’,’a’,’a’)`

What I wanted to see was `((‘a’,’a’),’a’)`.

In reality, ‘a’, ‘b’ etc. are custom objects with properties, grouped in arrays in jagged array $h.

**What is the most elegant way to solve this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this solve it for you? I removed `[0]` as I didn't see a use for it. I also made sure that multiple results are delivered in an outer array using `,`):

```
$h = ((‘a’,’b’,’a’), (‘c’,’d’), (‘a’, ‘f’)) 
$h | foreach { ,($_ | Where-Object {$_ -Like 'a'}) } | foreach { if ($_.Count -gt 0) {<% DO SOMETHING %> }}
```

Comment: `[0]` I put there to simulate a "property", but removed it after as it seemed confusing. Anyway, thanks. The `,` seems so obvious now.